# Why the javascript code isn't execute every time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this control in javascript and something is wrong because it seems that is not executed every time I make a change. I put alerts so I can see what's happening. What I do wrong?

`controlToSet` and `control1` are checboxs and `control2` is a radio button.

```
function SetValues(controlToSet, control1, control2) {

    if (control1.is(':checked') && control2.is(':checked')) {
        $(controlToSet).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(controlToSet).attr('checked', false);
        alert('checked and checked');
    }

    if (control1.is(':checked') && control2.is(':checked') == false) {
        $(controlToSet).attr('disabled', false);
        alert('checked an unchecked');
    }

    if (control1.is(':checked') == false && control2.is(':checked') == false) {
        $(controlToSet).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(controlToSet).attr('checked', false);
        alert('unchecked and unchecked');
    }
}
```

These controls are used in a web application and are depending one of the others and when one of theme is changing the value these javascript code is supposed to execute, but not all the time this is happening. What I do wrong?

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo which replicates the problem. How/when are you calling `SetValues`?

Comment: What do you mean by "make a change"?

Comment: Is it because you are missing the case where control2 is checked and control1 isn't?

Comment: You're missing the condition of "control1 is not checked, but control2 is checked"?

Comment: I'll add the obviously missing jQuery tag.

Comment: You should be using `.prop("disabled", true)` and `.prop("checked", false)` instead of `.attr`!

Comment: it seems you did not wrap control1 and control2 with $, but you only wrapped controlToSet.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your browser using a cached version of the javascript. Try clearing your brower cache, and/or restarting your browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to be executed when you make a change, you have to catch `change` events.

You can use the [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) binding function :

```
control1.add(control2).change(function(){
     SetValues(controlToSet, control1, control2)
});
```

Comment: This control is used in a web application and I want to execute this code if one of the controls is changing the value(check, uncheck, disabled). The controls are depending one of the others. I put that alert message so I can see and it seems that when I change a checkbox the javascript code is not execute. That is the problem.

Comment: @Florina The code I wrote calls your function when one of the two controls changes. Did you test it ?

Answer (score 0):

did forget the case  when  control1.is(':checked') == false && control2.is(':checked') ?